# Can I create an installable Google Chrome web app without going through the Chrome App Store?

Tags: web-applications, google-chrome, app-store

My ultimate goal is to use my web site without the URL bar.  As far as I can tell (for security reasons), the only way to do this is to make it an installable web app (or a Chrome extension -- maybe there is already such an extension?).  Can I simply provide the user with a link that gives Chrome all the necessary metadata it needs to install the app without actually going through the Chrome Web App Store?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create an extension and package it as an app (creating a .crx file) from chrome://extensions/ and then host the crx file on your own site or where ever; no Chrome Web App Store needed.

http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/apps.html

Comment: There is a lot of good information there. Thanks. As far as I can tell, hosted apps, packaged apps and extensions can all exist outside of the Chrome app store. Very cool that Chrome has all of those options.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, the feedback was correct in '11.  Chrome blocks out-of-store loading of extensions now.

Workaround:  http://www.ghacks.net/2012/06/12/chrome-fix-extensions-apps-and-user-scripts-cannot-be-installed-from-this-web-site/

For the OP, if you own the site, why not put it in the web store?